# How do I recover from a botched adopted storage migration? I can't take pictures or screenshots

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

TL;DR: I messed up. Now my phone won't store pictures because it's probably trying to write to some directory that doesn't exist. How can I fix this? What directory structure is expected? I caused it by maybe screwing up a bit when moving to Adopted Storage, but that may not be important for the answer.

---

I migrated to adopted storage this morning. I wanted a mixed partitioning, but accidentally got full-card adoption (i used the GUI). As part of that I suppose I migrated the existing `/storage/emulated` to the adopted storage.

Because I wanted a mixed setup and I had backups of my data, I just ran `sm partition ... mixed 25` and nuked the existing adopted storage.

Now I can't take any pictures. If I do a screenshot, it says it couldn't save it. If I take a picture with OpenCamera, it says the same.

I would like to avoid the hassle of factory resetting if it's just a matter of creating some directories and/or creating some symlinks. I tried setting up a symlink `/media/expand/&lt;my-adopted-storage>/user -> /storage/emulated` and created `DCIM` (mode `1777`) in `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` (where it used to be). That doesn't help.

Am I on the right track and just getting the details wrong, or am I screwed?

---

As you can see from the tags, I'm on CyanogenMod 13 / Android 6 / Marshmallow.

---

Further investigation:

Looked where OpenCamera is looking, and it's looking at `/sdcard/DCIM`. `/sdcard` is a symlink to `/storage/self/primary` and that's a symlink to `/mnt/user/0`. Tried creating a symlink to the existing `DCIM` there, didn't help. Maybe it needs to point to the right place in the system to slip through the security tracks? Trying a reboot and seeing where things end up.

EDIT: It was `/sdcard -> /storage/self/primary -> /mnt/user/0/primary`. I created `/mnt/user/0/primary -> /mnt/expand/*/user/0`. No go.

---

There is a secondary user on the phone. When I switch to that, I get a bunch of "Unfortunately YouTube/Gallery/foo stopped." and I can't run any of the installed apps -- then I get the same message.

---

I had three SD "Cards" listed in *Storage & USB*: Purple (successfully adopted), Grey (first adoption, now abandoned, said "not mounted") and *sdcard1*. I figured that maybe it's still yearning for that unmounted (nonexistent) partition, so I clicked it and chose "Forget". Now *sdcard1* is corrupt (!). Will reboot again and see what it makes of it.

---

Progress! After forgetting that original adoption and rebooting, now we have `/sdcard -> /storage/self/primary -> /storage/emulated/0`.

`/storage/emulated/0` is a FUSE system that seems to have the same size as `/data`, so things look pretty normal now. I took a screenshot, and `/sdcard/Pictures` was created.

`sdcard1` is back and looks fine.

---

Now there was a *Migrate data* command on both *Internal storage* and the adopted storage. When I clicked it on the adopted storage, `emulated/0` was remounted as a FUSE proxy for the adopted storage and screenshots now go there instead of to internal-internal. I think this is like I want it now.

Comment: I've got no experiences with adoptable storage – but if the location is any help: Screenshots usually go to `/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots` (at least that's where they were on all devices I've checked; I've never seen them going to `DCIM`, which is the *camera* app's default). I'd assume Android creates this directory automatically if it not exists – so maybe you can [check the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) while trying to take a screenshot? That might give some clues on what's going wrong.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the clues. Will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what solved my problem was that I ran *Migrate data* in the newest adopted storage. Until then the system was in a state where the abandoned adopted storage was the "primary storage", but wasn't present.

I'm not sure why *Migrate data* on *Internal storage* wasn't available before I abandoned the first adopted storage. Maybe all I would have had to do was to reboot and the command would have been available.

I am going to move more of the story from the answer to the question, to create a more coherent Q&A picture.